# Update sibling component via parent component in Angular 6?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular6

I have three components parent - room component with two child components roomslist and roomdetails, initially the roomslist component will be shown using ngif, when the user clicks add - roomdetails will be shown, once the user adds the room in the room details component, I need to display that in the roomlist page with the added room. Can anyone let me know how to acheieve it ?

--- Below is the code

```
    export class PropertyRoomComponent implements OnInit
{   
    @Output("saveRoomDetails") roomDetailsEvent: EventEmitter<RoomDetail>
    = new EventEmitter<RoomDetail>();
  @Input("roomDetail")
  public roomDetail:
  RoomDetail = { rateDetails: [], occupancy: [], roomDetails: [] };

   SaveRoom()
    { 
    this.roomDetailsEvent.emit(this.roomDetail);
    }
    }

export class RoomComponent implements OnInit
    {
  @Input('roomsList')
  public PropertyRooms: RoomDetail[];  
  SaveRoom(room)
  { 
    this.PropertyRooms.push(room);
    this.showAddRoomWindow = false;
  }  
  }



<room-list [rooms]="this.PropertyRooms" (GetRoomDetail)="GetRoomDetail($event)"></room-list>    

        export class PropertyRoomListComponent implements OnInit {

  public BedType: any;

  public roomAmenities: any;

  @Input('rooms')
  roomsList: RoomDetail[];

 @Output("GetRoomDetail")
 GetRoomDetailEvent : EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter<any>();

  constructor(){
  console.log(this.roomsList); // undefined
  }
```

Comment: What you have tried so far? Can u please share some relevant code

Comment: `roomcomponent` should probably own the list of rooms and pass it down to `roomslist` via an `@Input` parameter. `roomdetails` can then have an `@Output` parameter which emits an event when a room is added. `roomcomponent` listens for that event and updates the list of rooms, and `roomslist` will re-render.

Comment: Or you can still do the event thing, but instead of `roomcomponent` owning the list of rooms, it can grab the `roomslist` component using `ViewChild` and maybe call a method on it like `addRoom`. But that's probably not as clean. Notifying each other via services/observables is another solution.

Answer (score 0):

This is a basic state management question. You need to persist your Rooms some where. There are a few ways to do that.

1. Input and Output events. This requires you to emit values from the child to the parent every time a change is made and can get overly complicated if you start emitting too many events.
2. Service/Providers! Singleton services allow you to share a reference to a variable, like `Rooms`. So any edit from your child components can be seen in the parent component, or any other component that injects the service.
3. Ngrx. The redux pattern is similar to dependency injection but forces you to follow a strict pattern to access state.